# valgrind not working on OS X 10.8

Tags: valgrind, osx-mountain-lion

Every time I try to run `valgrind` on my OS X 10.8 notebook, I get:

```
bad executable (no stack)
valgrind: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file
```

What is the problem? How can I fix this? Everything works fine on Linux, so it's not that I'm somehow misusing `valgrind`. The exact line I'm using is `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./a.out`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was getting the same error, but I just upgraded valgrind to `3.8.1` (`brew upgrade valgrind` using HomeBrew for me), and it works, although running Valgrind prints the following warning:

```
WARNING: Support on MacOS 10.8 is experimental and mostly broken.
WARNING: Expect incorrect results, assertions and crashes.
WARNING: In particular, Memcheck on 32-bit programs will fail to
WARNING: detect any errors associated with heap-allocated data.
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Apparently I was using the latest version, but using the package from SVN, which somehow did not work. Doing a `brew remove valgrind; brew install valgrind` finally installed `3.8.1`.

Comment: In my case this was due to upgrading from Lion to Mountain Lion. Updating itself may not work if you already have the latest version. In order to force recompilation, follow @houbysoft's steps (above comment).

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem using valgrind with macports. It turns out I needed to install with

```
sudo port install valgrind +universal
```

I was trying to valgrind a 32bit executable and I believe that without +universal, 32bit support was not being compiled in.